# Wordpress not reading stylesheet

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to wordpress development. I am learning to develop a new theme. I know for basic there are only two absolutely necessary files for a wordpress theme. For testing I created an index.php file and style.css fiel and tried to use it as a theme. But I am facing issues doing it.

The index.php file is being read and the content is being shown on the home page, but the css isn't getting loaded from the style.css file. The first comment is being read as the theme info can be seen in theme details section but the css isn't being loaded.

I am getting two kinds of error, first

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404(Not Found)"
Refer to the image:
[image]

And,
"GET http://rockstargaming.hol.es/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)"
[image]

At first I was trying to include the stylesheet thorugh `<link>` tag but after getting the error I tried another way to enqueue scripts - through funstions.php file, but then I see nothing, no error and no styling.

Nothing seems to be working, I tried doing everything multiple times.

index.php:-

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Gym</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            Testing theme development
        </div>
        <div class="top-ribbon top-ribbon-left"></div>
        <div class="top-ribbon top-ribbon-right"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
/*
Theme Name: GymTheme
Author: SamarpitShrivastava
Author URI: https://www.google.com
Version: 1.0
*/

html,body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 10px;
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
}

/*Upper Ribbon*/

/*Phone*/
.top-ribbon-left{
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #ffd900, #ffb700);
    width: 81%;
    height: 13em;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -3em;

    transform: rotateZ(-10deg);

    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5 5 yellow;
}

.top-ribbon-right{
    border-top: 18em solid #ffb700;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 35em solid transparent;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    right: 1em;
    margin-right: -3em;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    transform: rotateZ(6deg);

    z-index: 200;
}
/*Phone*/

/*Tablet*/
@media only screen  and (min-width: 800px){
  /* For Tablets: */

    .top-ribbon-left{
        background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #ffd900, #ffb700);
        width: 80%;
        height: 17em;
        float: left;
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: -3em;
        transform: rotateZ(-10deg);

        z-index: 1;
    }

    .top-ribbon-right{
        border-top: 25em solid #ffb700;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: 49em solid transparent;
        float: right;
        position: absolute;
        right: 1em;
        margin-right: -3em;
        margin-top: -1em;
        transform: rotateZ(6deg);

        z-index: 200;
    }

}
/*Tablet*/

/*Desktop*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 1300px) {
  /* For desktop: */

    .top-ribbon-left{
        background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #ffd900, #ffb700);
        width: 80%;
        height: 20em;
        float: left;
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: -3em;
        transform: rotateZ(-10deg);

        z-index: 1;
    }

    .top-ribbon-right{
        border-top: 30em solid #ffb700;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: 60em solid transparent;
        float: right;
        position: absolute;
        right: 1em;
        margin-right: -3em;
        margin-top: 0em;
        transform: rotateZ(6deg);

        z-index: 200;
    }

}
/*Desktop*/

/*Upper Ribbon*/
```

functions.php

```
<?php

function includeResources(){
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'includeResources');

?>
```

This is how it should be actually looking:
[image]

Comment: You have a typo in there: "function inculdeResources()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you are adding the style path to the header incorrectly.
Example: bluebezer.com.br/style.css

you should be pointing to the folder where your css is which is within the themes and not at the root of the site.
Example: bluebezer.com/wp-content/themes/your-name/style.css

to get the path of your theme use the function get_template_directory_uri()

```
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
    <head>
        <!-- ... other codes ...-->

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css'; ?>" />

        <!-- This wp_head function must be present in all wordpress headers. -->
        <?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head>
```

but the correct way to add a wordpress style is by creating a function in functions.php and adding code similar to the one below:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpsites_new_style_sheet' );
function wpsites_new_style_sheet() {
    //registering a new style in wordpress
    wp_register_style( 'new-style', get_template_directory_uri() .'css/new-style.css', array(), '1.0');
    //stating that the new style should be displayed in wordpress
    wp_enqueue_style( 'new-style' );    
}
```

It is important to note that this function will automatically call the style of your site header via the wp_head(); function; which should be present in all wordpress theme headers.

The wp_head(); function is responsible for displaying titles, scripts, styles, goals and other information that comes from plugins, actions, and wordpress panel settings automatically. Then it must be present in all wordpress headers or you will have various errors and difficulties during development.

Another important thing is the function: wp_footer();
It is responsible for calling extra information like scripts and other settings similar to wp_head(); and she must always be present in the example's footer:

```
    <!-- ... other codes ...-->
    <?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your stylesheet isn't located in the root directory of your WordPress installation (`/style.css`) but in your theme directory. This is why you should not use the HTML `link` attribute but rather the [wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) function in the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action. You could use the official [WordPress guide](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/#enqueuing-scripts-and-styles) for this.

Furthermore, your `functions.php` is not valid, as `style.css` is not declared as a string. A PHP error should be thrown.
Change this `wp_enqueue_style('style', style.css, false);` to `wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());`.
Moreover, the function you want to include does not exist because of a typo. Rename the function to `includeResources` instead of `inculdeResources` (switch u and l).

Comment: Hello! Actually first I tried using "get_stylesheet_uri()" function in the includeResources function arguements, but even then it wasn;t working, then I read something on wordpress codex and I tried to use it but it didn;t help. I have updated the code in the question and this was also not working, and even after the wp_footer, it isn't working as needed.